# Telepot on python, can't send multiple photos with sendGroupMedia

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-3.9, telepot

I'm trying to send 2 or 3 photos at the same time, so they're displayed as one message on my channel.
To send one photos I used python's `requests` library, with this line of code;

```py
pic = {'photo' : open('p.jpeg', 'rb')}
print(requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{apiKey}/sendPhoto?chat_id={chat_id}?disable_notification=True', files=pic))
```

Now to send more at once I use `telepot`. I'm doing this:

```py
bot = telepot.Bot(apiKey)
bot.sendMediaGroup(
    chat_id=chat_id,
    media=[
        {'media' : open( 'p.jpeg', 'rb')},
        {'media' : open('p1.jpeg', 'rb')}
    ],
    disable_notification=True
)
```

The problem is I don't precise the type of media being transferred.
I tried doing :

```py
media = {'media' :      
                    {'photo' : open( 'p.jpeg', 'rb')},
                    {'photo' : open('p1.jpeg', 'rb')}
        }
```

But `media` parameter must be an array.

I also tried to pass a double sized dictionary as argument to `requests.get(...)`, it didn't work either.

Could you guys help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved, eventually I had to do this:

```py
bot.sendMediaGroup(
    chat_id=chat_id,
    media=[
        {'media' : open( 'p.jpeg', 'rb'), 'type' : 'photo'},
        {'media' : open('p1.jpeg', 'rb'), 'type' : 'photo'}
    ],
    disable_notification=True
)
```